# DRY-ing JS code and hiding input on address bar?

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a script which would pass input of the user onto the completed.html page but here are two problems:

1. All of the user inputs are displayed on the address bar, i want to hide it but i dont want to use the POST method which will ruin the purpose of my JS script. Is there any way i can hide those inputs without changing the method even if i have to change the JS script?
2. My JS code is really repetitious, it's repeated 4 times and i want to know a better way of writing it without copy and pasting all over?

index.html

```
<div id="container">
    <header>
        <h1>Registration Form</h1>
        <hr>
    </header>
    <article>
        <form action="completed.html" method="GET">
            <label for="FirstName"><b>First Name:</b></label>
            <input name="FirstName" type="text" placeholder="John" required>
            <label for="LastName"><b>Last Name:</b></label>
            <input name="LastName" type="text" placeholder="Doe" required>
            <label for="email"><b>Email:</b></label>
            <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="example@mail.com" required>
            <label for="password"><b>Password:</b></label>
            <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password here." required>
            <p></p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </article>
    <footer>
        Copyright @ 2017 Name
    </footer>
</div>
```

completed.html

```
<div id="container">
    <header>
        <h1>Registration Completed!</h1>
        <hr>
    </header>
    <article>
        <div id="info" style="float: left;">
            <p>Thank you for registering on our site! An verification email has been seen to your email address! To make sure we got everything right, we would like you to review the infomation you've put in.</p>
            <div id="fn">
                Your First Name is:
            </div>
            <div id="ln">
                Your Last Name is:
            </div>
            <div id="em">
                Your email is:
            </div>
            <div id="pw">
                Your password is:
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
    <footer>
        Copyright @ 2017 Name
    </footer>
</div>
<script>
    function processForm() {
        var ary = location.search.substring(1).split("&");

        var fnpart = ary[0].split("=");
        frn = unescape(fnpart[1]);
        document.getElementById("fn").innerHTML = "<b>Your First Name is:</b>" + "<br>" + frn;

        var lnpart = ary[1].split("=");
        lsn = unescape(lnpart[1]);
        document.getElementById("ln").innerHTML = "<b>Your Last Name is:</b>" + "<br>" + lsn;

        var empart = ary[2].split("=");
        ema = unescape(empart[1]);
        document.getElementById("em").innerHTML = "<b>Your Email is:</b>" + "<br>" + ema;

        var pwpart = ary[3].split("=");
        psw = unescape(pwpart[1]);
        document.getElementById("pw").innerHTML = "<b>Your First Name is:</b>" + "<br>" + psw;
    }
    processForm();
</script>
```

Comment: Can't you use a browser storage to store the data, and send the same data using `Ajax  - GET` request. You can always read from cookies, localstorage, sessionstorage etc. Your form has already method as `GET` which is obviously show the params in URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with a pattern like below, using the loop index to match the position in the short names/ long names :

But the password shouldn't be visible in the location like it is now !

```
var names = [['fn', 'First Name'], 
             ['ln', 'Last Name'],
             ['em', 'Email'],
             ['pw', 'Password']
            ]

for (ind in ary){
  var part = unescape(ary[ind].split("=")[1]);
  document.getElementById(names[ind][0]).innerHTML = "<b>Your "+ names[ind][1] + " is:</b> <br>" + part;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the script makeover, but the inputs are still visible. I removed all the 4 vars and paste the code, is it correct that way?

Comment: @MatiasTresch sorry i was blind for the first goal,  i've only factorized the code, did you try Zamrony-p-juhara suggestion ?

Comment: Zamrony Technique is fine, he used 1 page but i prefer the 2 pages way. Is there a way for that? Because i would have to make it so that  it changes the whole page layout (text) with his way.

Comment: @MatiasTresch  i can't see a way to do it without a POST method

Comment: Ok what can you do to achieve the same result with the POST method?

Comment: I believe POST data will not be available to client-side javascript.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish goal no. 1, you do not need to use attribute `action` on `form`. Also you can replace submit button with `<input type="button">` and handle click event and call `processForm()` function.

To be able to call that function, you need to move `processForm()` declaration into index.html. so you only need one file. You do not need to read any data from query string. Just read input value from DOM element

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But is there a way i can do it with 2 seperated pages?

Comment: This answer makes no sense

Comment: Can you explain why  it makes no sense?